# What are formats in LaTeX and how to manage them?

Tags: texlive, fmtutil

For very long time I am trying to understand why we need `fmtutil` and also why these files are called formats? Where are they coming from (besides language packages)? For example I have checked my system-wide `fmtutil.conf` and found lines like

```
dviluatex   luatex  language.def,language.dat.lua   dviluatex.ini
luajittex   luajittex   language.def,language.dat.lua   luatex.ini
mf  mf-nowin        -   -translate-file=cp227.tcx mf.ini
pdftex  pdftex  language.def    -translate-file=cp227.tcx *pdfetex.ini
etex    pdftex  language.def    -translate-file=cp227.tcx *etex.ini
pdfetex pdftex  language.def    -translate-file=cp227.tcx *pdfetex.ini
tex     tex     -   tex.ini
```

and so on. Intuition says these are about language-specific files (well, paths like language.def show it), but overall purpose and fields are as magic as unicorns, what are they for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I will restrict my explanations to formats and their handling in TeX Live. MikTeX has a different approach I guess.

To add to David's explanation, formats are defined in the so called `TLPOBJ`, these are the stanzas (paragraphs) you can see in the `texlive.tlpdb` (which is in `PATH/TO/TEXLIVE/2019/tlpkg/texlive.tlpdb`). An example:

```
name aleph
category Package
revision 50602
...
execute AddFormat name=aleph engine=aleph options=*aleph.ini           fmttriggers=cm,hyphen-base,knuth-lib,plain
execute AddFormat name=lamed engine=aleph patterns=language.dat           options=*lambda.ini           fmttriggers=cm,hyphen-base,antomega,lambda,latex,latex-fonts,omega
...
```

This adds two format definitions. In the TLPDB we are using `key=value` pairs, from which the `fmtutil.cnf` is generated. (Ignore the `fmttriggers` for now, they are internal features to trigger rebuilds)

The definitions in turn come from the macro package writers and are put into the source files for the tlpobj by us (TL Team).

Most of the formats are defined in the respective engine package:

- `aleph` engine is in `aleph` package and defined `aleph` and `lamed`
- `context` package provides all kinds of `cont-XX` formats
- `cslatex` package provides `cslatex` and `pdfcslatex` formats
- ...

Some formats, in particular the base latex formats, get a special treatment, though.

Concerning the language question: As David said, hyphenation patterns can only be loaded during format creation time, and in addition different engines (binary programs) use different formats of hyphenation pattern definitions, thus we need to have the file to be loaded in the configuration file.

Answer (score 10):

A format file is just a preloaded set of definitions to speed up document processing. "pdflatex" for example is just "pdftex" with the definitions in `latex.ltx` preloaded. Actually these days not loading latex.ltx on every document only saves a fraction of a second, when the system was designed it would save tens of minutes per document.

Related to this the `\patterns` instructions that set up language-specific hyphenation can only be loaded in initex mode (which is set up for dumping formats) which is why you see a specification of which files to load in the config file.